# Is there a philosophy about how philosophy is no better than instinct?

Tags: history, thought

Troubles with the circularity of the title question aside, most of philosophy seems to involve conscious thought. This conscious thought involves careful reflection upon matters and reasoning based on primitives which come down to intuition.

Is there a philosophy that simply argues against the execution of this process in the first place? A frame of mind that simply argues against any and all forms of deliberate, conscious thought.

If all our decisions depend upon core primitives, why not try to completely run on instinct and try your best to **not** consciously deep dive into any philosophical matter? Instead, why not just follow your natural dispositions towards any side of any philosophical discussion? This saves the most important resources of all: time and energy. This argument may be made more strong since we often invent philosophical reasons to justify our preconceived intuitions anyways, rather than consciously come up with arguments to argue against these intuitions (I.e. confirmation bias)

What would this be called and is this at all related to pragmatism or different?

Comment: Almost all eastern philosophies — Taoism, Zen, traditional Buddhism — would say something to the effect _Thought is not a solution but the (principal) problem_

Comment: "*As nature has taught us the use of our limbs, without giving us the knowledge of the muscles and nerves by which they are actuated; so she has implanted in us an instinct, which carries forward the thought in a correspondent course to that which she has established among external objects; though we are ignorant of those powers and forces, on which this course and succession of objects totally depends*", EHU 5.22 - [Hume's solution](https://iep.utm.edu/hume-causation/#H5) to the problem of causality. “*Reason is, and ought only to be the slave of the passions*” T 2.3.3.4.

Comment: And yes, Peirce imported much of Hume's psychology into his pragmatism, but with caution:"*Fortunately (I say it advisedly) man is not so happy as to be provided with a full stock of instincts to meet all occasions, and so is forced upon the adventurous business of reasoning... When one’s purpose lies in the line of novelty, invention, generalization, theory – in a word, improvement of the situation – by the side of which happiness appears a shabby old dud – instinct and the rule of thumb manifestly cease to be applicable*", CP 2.178, see [Boyd](https://journals.openedition.org/ejpap/1035).